# How to create navigation routes with ngRoute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create the following simple navigation:

html:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="pages/sub1">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/sub2">sub2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/pages/sub1", {
        templateUrl : "templates/sub1.html",
        controller : "sub1Controller"
    }).when("/pages/sub2", {
        templateUrl : "templates/sub2.html",
        controller : "sub2Controller"
    }).otherwise({
        templateUrl : "templates/error.html"
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Result: the URL path is changed to `localhost/pages/sub1` when clicking on a link, as expected. *But* the ng-view is not updated and remains blank! Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add # before the url in href field of anchor tag.

Replace your code with this :

```
<li><a href="#/pages/sub1">sub1</a></li>
<li><a href="#/pages/sub2">sub2</a></li>
```

Refer this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmckeachie/aq676/light/)

Comment: There is no need in # with $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Answer (score 1):

I have made 2 adjustments:
1. Added / to link:

```
<li><a href="/pages/sub1">sub1</a></li>
```

2. Added requireBase: false to config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

I have also putted templates inside HTML just to make it work inside snippet. Full examplae:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/sub1">sub1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/sub2">sub2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

            angular.module('myapp').controller('sub1Controller', function () {
                
            });
            angular.module('myapp').controller('sub2Controller', function () {
                
            });

            app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when("/pages/sub1", {
                    templateUrl: "/templates/sub1.html",
                    controller: "sub1Controller"
                }).when("/pages/sub2", {
                    templateUrl: "/templates/sub2.html",
                    controller: "sub2Controller"
                }).otherwise({
                    templateUrl: "/templates/error.html"
                });

                $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                    enabled: true,
                    requireBase: false
                });
            });
        </script>
        
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/templates/sub1.html">
            First View
        </script>
        
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/templates/sub2.html">
            Second View
        </script>
        
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/templates/error.html">
            404
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```